# Error: aggregate has incomplete type and cannot be defined

Tags: c++, c++11, incomplete-type

I am writing a program for bank and I m getting this error when I compile it.
This is my entire code as i was not able to share more code here it is on paste bin. [My code](https://pastebin.com/FQBPKmSv)

I am not including my whole code but the part I think is responsible:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<limits>
#include<fstream>
#include<iomanip>

using std::ios_base;
using std::ostringstream;
using std::ios;
using std::fstream;
using std::ifstream;
using std::ofstream;
using std::stoi;
using std::to_string;
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::getline;

class yourbankaccount
{
private:
    string accountNumber;
    // Name of the customer.
    string name;
    // Date of birth
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    // Get Age
    int age;
    // Get Gender
    string gender;
    long accountBalance = 0;
public:
    friend int getInt(string info, int length);
    friend string getStr(string info, int length);
    yourbankaccount(){}
    void setAccountNumber(string number){
        accountNumber = number;
    }
    string shareAccountNumber(){
        return accountNumber;
    }
    // Get date
    void getDate(){
        int d, m, y;
        cout << "Now please enter your Date Of Birth(DD/MM/YYYY):"<<endl;
        d = getInt("Day(DD)", 2);
        m = getInt("Month(MM)", 2);
        y = getInt("Year(YYYY)", 4);
        day = d; month = m; year = y;
    }
    // Return Date
    string sendDate(){
        string Date = to_string(day) + "/" + to_string(month) + "/" + to_string(year);
        return Date;
    }
    // Method to add details.
    void getCustomerDetails(){
        bool gotGen = false;
        string n; int a; unsigned int p; char g;
        cout << "Please fill in the following details: ";
        name = getStr("Name of Account holder", 45);
        cout << "Enter your birthday in given format: ";
        getDate();
        age = getInt("your Age", 2);
        do
        {
            gender = getStr("your Gender(only M for Male, F for Female, O for Other)", 1);
            if (stringToUpper(gender)  != "M" || 
                stringToUpper(gender) != "F" || 
                stringToUpper(gender) != "O"){
                    "Please enter only M or F or O!";
            }else{
                gotGen = true;
            }
        } while (gotGen);
    } 
    string shareName(){
        return name;
    }
    string shareDOB(){
        return sendDate();
    }
    int shareAge(){
        return age;
    }
    string shareGender(){
        return gender;
    }
    void setAccountBalance(long bal){
        accountBalance = bal;
    }
    long shareAccountBalance(){
        return accountBalance;
    }
    ~yourbankaccount(){}
};
```

and I am declaring the object here:

```
void createAccount(){
    ofstream addAccount;
    yourbankaccount Account;
    cout << "Thank You for Choosing Your Bank.";
    cout << "Please provide The folling details.";
    Account.setAccountNumber(calNewAccNumber());
    Account.getCustomerDetails();
    Account.setAccountBalance(500);
    int pin = getInt("a pin for the account", 4);
    string file ="accounts/open.csv";
    addAccount.open(file, ios::out | ios::app);
    if (addAccount.is_open())
    {
        addAccount << Account.shareAccountNumber()
        << "," << pin << "," << "\"" << Account.shareName() << "\"" << "," 
        << Account.shareDOB() <<"," << Account.shareAge()
        << "," << Account.shareGender() << Account.shareAccountBalance()<<"\n";
    }

    cout << "Your Account has been created Sucessfully." <<
            "Please note your number as it will be required for logging in\n";
    cout << "Account number is:" << Account.shareAccountNumber() << "\n";
}
```

I get this error when I compile it:

````
> Executing task: C/C++: g++.exe build active file ver(1) <

Starting build...
D:\Programs\mingw_w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -g D:\BSC_IT\sem_2\OOPS\CA2\YourBank\yourbank.cpp -o 
D:\BSC_IT\sem_2\OOPS\CA2\YourBank\yourbank.exe
```
D:\BSC_IT\sem_2\OOPS\CA2\YourBank\yourbank.cpp: In function 'void createAccount()':
D:\BSC_IT\sem_2\OOPS\CA2\YourBank\yourbank.cpp:139:21: error: aggregate 'yourbankaccount Account' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
    yourbankaccount Account;
                     ^~~~~~~
```
Build finished with error(s).
The terminal process terminated with exit code: -1.

>Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
````

Comment: Post a [mre] as required here please.

Comment: Probably, you haven't included the header that defines `yourbankaccount` into the source file that tries to use it.

Comment: I have defined it in the same file

Comment: Defined or declared? Please create a proper [mcve]. A good one is one we can copy and build ourselves to replicate the exact error you ask about (but nothing more). And please remember the *minimal* part, most of the code you current show is irrelevant for the problem.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have added a link to my whole code. I hope this helps to find the error. Thanks and sorry I didn't know what to share here and as there is a limit on how much code I can add i did not share my whole code.

Comment: Please do not post links to code. Instead, post a [mcve]. To make one, take your whole code and start throwing away irrelevant parts. Each time, verify that you are still getting the same error. Once you cannot throw away any more stuff, you have a [mcve].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your class type is [incomplete](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type#Incomplete_type). You need to [define](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) your class **before** you can declare an object of that class. It is not enough to [forward declare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class) the class.